# Anomaly detection with geo spatial data

Tags: spatial, anomaly-detection, geostatistics

I have geo spatial data.
Dataset represents concentration of something. For instance, social media activity of people in point [time, lat, lon]

I have some list of feature for every points (lat, lon): 
constantly value for every time
max value in time slice, more than average value in time slice etc

How can I detect anomalies within these dataset? What method should I use to detect anomalies?
I think to collect points (lot, lan) because their have features listed above. 
Then I have to use clustering methods for this points which were collected

Which methods can be appropriate?